# Why do we pick $n_1$ and $n_2$ instead of just $n$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Ghorpade/Limaye's: Course in Calculus and Real Analysis: There is this proof that the limit is unique:

> [image]

I am confused with a small detail: Why do we assume that there is $n_1$ and $n_2$ instead of just $n$? I mean, we are talking about the same sequence $(a_n)$, taking $n_1,n_2$ seems to mean that we are talking about the hypothetical sequences in which $n_1=6$ and $n_2=4$:

$$a_1\quad a_2\quad a_3\quad a_4\quad a_5\quad a_6$$

$$a_1\quad a_2\quad a_3\quad a_4$$

But it doesn't seems to make sense because a sequence is defined as $a_n : \Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{R}$, shouldn't we expect that $n_1=n_2$? Or this process is made to give the idea that we are taking the best bound possible?

Comment: Same sequence but different limits. Hence different $n$.

Comment: You don't get to **choose** them! The definition of limits just asserts their existence! i.e. "pick an $\epsilon$, get an $n$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** The value of $n_1$ obtained from the definition of $a_n \to a$ depends on $a$, and the value of $n_2$ obtained from the definition of $a_n \to b$ depends on $b$, so the two values $n_1$ and $n_2$ can't be assumed to be equal.

---

**Long answer:** For a fixed sequence $(x_n)$ and a fixed real number $x$, the definition of the statement $x_n \to x$ says that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that a particular condition holds, namely that $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

Here you have a fixed sequence $(a_n)$ and fixed real numbers $a,b$. Moreover, you've fixed a particular value of $\varepsilon > 0$, namely $|a-b|$.

- The definition of $a_n \to a$ tells you that there exists $N$ such that some condition holds, namely that $|a_n-a| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$; and
- The definition of $a_n \to b$ tells you that there exists $N$ such that another condition holds, namely that $|a_n-b| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

The issue is that these definitions are independent of each other, since $a$ and $b$ are (by assumption) not equal. This means that the two values of $N$ cannot be taken to be equal. Indeed, $N$ can be thought of as a threshold for being close to the limit: the threshold for being close to $a$ might be distinct from the threshold for being close to $b$.

Thus, the value of $N$ given by the first definition is called $n_1$ in your proof; and the value of $N$ given by the second definition is called $n_2$.

These distinct values are then reconciled by taking their maximum, since if you're beyond both the threshold for being close to $a$ and beyond the threshold for being close to $b$, then you must be beyond both thresholds.

Comment: What bugs me is that if the sequence converges, shouldn't we expect $n_1$ and $n_2$ to go "as far as possible"? This seems to tell me that it is irrelevant if $n_1$ is different of $n_2$. For example: Suppose we have:

$$a_n \to a \quad \quad a_n \to b$$

Now, suppose we have a sequence of fixed epsilons: $\epsilon_1 > \epsilon_2 > \epsilon_3 > \dots$, this means that we can take the first $\epsilon$ and find certain $m_1,n_1$'s

$$|a_{n_{1}}  - a|<\epsilon_1 \quad \quad |a_{m_{1}} -b|<\epsilon_1 $$

Now taking $\epsilon_2$, we have (cont...)

Comment: $$|a_{n_{2}} -a|<\epsilon_2 \quad \quad |a_{m_{2}} -b|<\epsilon_2 $$

And again, we have to find $m_2,n_2$ but now $m_2>m_1$ and $n_2 > n_1$. And hence, they both increase in each of the inequations. This is the reason that seems to indicate that we could operate with $n_1=n_2$ or at least, indicate that the difference could be irrelevant.

Comment: Right, once you have a single value of $n_1$, arbitrarily large values work; likewise for $n_2$. The problem is, before you know a value of $n_1$ and a value of $n_2$, you don't know how large the common value (called $n_0$ in this proof) has to be in order to exceed both. As an analogy, suppose Alice and Bob are each thinking of a number - what you have to do is pick a number which is greater than or equal to both their numbers. You can't do this unless you know what both the numbers are.

Answer (score 2):

This simply follows from the definition of limit.

Saying that $a_n\to a$ means that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $|a-a_n|<\varepsilon$ for every $n>N$.

If we suppose in all generality that $a_n\to a$, $a_n\to b$ we have no reason to suppose that the "first" $N$ is equal to the "second" $N$; we are merely supposing that two such natural numbers exist.

From there, it is easy to show that the $\varepsilon$ property holds for the maximum of these numbers, which is exactly what you are saying: the basic statement is somewhat weaker.

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence could converge to different values, $a$ and $b$ then it wouldn't necessarily be true that $n_1 = n_2$. There are good answers here that explain why.

But, to clarify what $n_1$ and $n_2$ are, they are the point(s) in the sequence beyond which $|a_n - a| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a_n - b| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ respectively. So, for $n_1$, say the  relevant terms in the sequence are

$
a_{n_1}, a_{n_1 + 1}, a_{n_1 + 2}, \ldots
$

All of which are within $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ of the limit, $a$. The terms we are talking about are **not**

$
a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_{n_1}
$

i.e. the the first $n_1$ (or $n_2$) terms of the sequence.

(The way I read your question it seemed like there may be some confusion on this point. Sorry if that's not what you were saying.)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is something more fundamental that confuses you. In mathematics,  saying "let $a,b$ be real numbers" does not presume $a\neq b$! Using different symbols just to allow of every possibility. So $a$ may or may not be $= b$. You can think of the statement as "take two real numbers $a,b$ out of $\mathbb{R}$ one at a time **with replacement**"; so here certainly $a$ may or may not be equal to $b$, and $a,b$ simply represent the first real number and the second real number respectively.

I guess you can solve your problem now. It is just that the author wants to allow of the possibility of $n_{1}=n_{2}$ as well as that of $n_{1}\neq n_{2}$, which follows from the possibility that $a=b$ or that $a\neq b$.